# Maclaurin series of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-2x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am not sure if I am doing this right.

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-2x}$$

So first I find the first four derivatives.

$$f'(x) = \frac{2}{(1-2x)^2}$$

$$f''(x) = \frac{8}{(1-2x)^3}$$

$$f'''(x) = \frac{48}{(1-2x)^4}$$

$$f''''(x) = \frac{384}{(1-2x)^5}$$

From this I can see that a general form would be something like

$\frac{2n*something}{(1-2x)^n}$

Or

$$2n*something*(1-2x)^{-1-n}$$

Trying to find something is hard. I give up, it might take me weeks to derive it.

I know that the something is related to the previous answer, it is the numerator so I could get it by referencing it to that but I think I need it in ns and a recursive definition would be bad.

I can get the first something by using n since it is 1. The second something is is again n.

The third something is harder, it isn't n or n! but it is $n! + 2$ but that doesn't help because the fourth n is not that.

It isn't $2^n$ because that doesn't fit the second or last ones.

Comment: You have a sign change from - to + between the original function and the derivatives.  This is incorrect. Please clarify which sign you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick and interesting way to do this problem: use the fact that for a convergent geometric series, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}z^k=\frac{1}{1-z}
$$
Now, using this equality in reverse, we can set $z=2x$ to find
$$
\frac{1}{1-2x}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(2x)^k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^k x^k
$$

---

So what exactly went wrong with your way?  Nothing, really.  It's just that it is generally difficult to find the necessary pattern by looking only at the expression $f^{(n)}(x)$.  We could do things your way, as follows:

$$
f'(0) = \frac{2}{(1-2(0))^2} = 2\\
f''(0)= \frac{2^2\cdot 2}{(1-2(0))^3} =2^2\cdot 2= 8\\
f'''(0)= \frac{2^3\cdot (3\times 2)}{(1-2(0))^4} =2^3\cdot (3\times 2)= 48\\
f^{(4)}(0)= \frac{2^4\cdot (4\times3\times 2)}{(1-2(0))^5} =2^4\cdot (4\times3\times 2)= 384\\
$$
Presented this way, the pattern is a bit more obvious, and we find
$$
\vdots\\
f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{2^n\cdot n!}{(1-2(0))^{(n+1)}} = 2^n\cdot n!\\
$$
The MacLaurin series is then
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^k\cdot k!}{k!}x^k
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^k x^k
$$
So is this way worse?  Not necessarily. However, it's important to remember that when you get stuck on a problem, you could always try approaching it from a different angle.

Comment: I don't follow. What was wrong with my way?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with computing derivatives and trying to find the pattern. But in problems like these it is best to use this method. You use other properties of series (such as the geometric series in this case) to get the power series representation you want. Not only does this give you the answer quickly it gives you the radius of convergence for free.

Comment: What is a radius of convergence and why do I need to know it? All I need to know is is the Maclaruin series and the interval which it is valid.//

Comment: If you haven't learnt it that's fine. Don't worry about it. Important thing is it gives the Mclaurin series you are looking for. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer and gave a critique of your original approach, which I hope you find helpful.  As for the "radius of convergence": that's just half of the length of the interval over which the series is valid.  In other words, since the radius of convergence of this series is $\frac12$, we know that the series will be valid over any $x$ in $\left(-\frac12, \frac12\right)$. Sometimes, it's more convenient to talk about the radius than the interval itself, especially since we don't always know how the series behaves on the endpoints of the interval.

Answer (score 3):

We know from properties of geometric series that

$$ \frac{1}{1-x}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n, \quad \quad |x| <1$$

Thus,

$$ \frac{1}{1-2x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2x)^n, \quad \quad |2x| <1$$

This gives us (By the uniqueness of power series representation) the maclaurin series for your function is

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n x^n$$ with $|x| <\frac 12$

The radius of convergence is $1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Think about how you do each derivative, without simplifying the constants.

$$
f(x) = (1-2x)^{-1}
$$
$$
f'(x) = (-1)(1-2x)^{-2}(-2)
$$
$$
f''(x) = (-1)(-2)(1-2x)^{-3}(-2)(-2)
$$
$$
f'''(x) = (-1)(-2)(-3)(1-2x)^{-4}(-2)(-2)(-2)
$$

The terms we're building up on the left look like...?  And the ones one the right?  You should see the pattern at this point.

Comment: So is this a standard method to memorize and replicate on all of these problems or just this one?

Comment: It is a way to see what the underlying pattern is.  I can't speak for it's generality for "these problems" since I'm not sure what kinds of functions you're making Maclaurin expansions for.  It seems to me that it will help you see patterns when making series for most functions.

Answer (score 1):

How do you go from $1-2x$ to $1+2x$? And also, you might want to keep track of the factor $2$ coming from $2x$ separately from the power, which increases (and lends a factor) each time you differentiate.

Hint: in your calculations you have $2\cdot 1$; $4\cdot 2\cdot 1$; $8\cdot3\cdot 2\cdot 1$; $16 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2\cdot 1$ - can you see the pattern from that?

Comment: It was obviously a typo. How did you know to rearragange them in that order? To me it was obvious there was a factor of 2n so I pulled it out.

Comment: @PaulthePirate I guess it is experience. Up to checking signs, there will be an extra factor $2$ every time because of the $2x$ and the chain rule. And there will be a factor $n$ because of the power in the denominator. I learned not to cancel or consolidate things too quickly in this kind of problem, because it obscures the pattern. I think it is helpful to understand how the Maclaurin Series relates to the Binomial expansion, because you will want to be able to use the easiest method.